# How to bypass response filter when response is from exception mapper

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Is there a way to bypass response filter execution in exception case?

Say I have an exception mapper to create a response for certain exception and I don't want response filter executed for this case.

I only want my response filter executed for normal 200 case.

I saw ContainerResponse has some property to indicate it's from exception.
But that requires each response filter to do the check accordingly.

Is there any way else like using some annotation or config to mark this response filter only for 200?

Thanks

Leon

Comment: No, it's just how it's designed.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot!